# Securing the token of a token based authentication system

Tags: php, jquery, api, http, token

I am using a token based authentication for accessing a few crude web APIs I have designed for my site. At login, the username and password are posted to the login API, and it generates a token with a unique secret key, and the key is stored on the database. At each subsequent call, the token is sent with the request and verified on the server with the secret key.

I am using a web app to consume this API service and deliver a front end to the users. The web application is designed using HTML/Bootstrap/JQuery and the backend is written on php.

I have successfully tested my app and the token based authentication works. However, I have one concern. I find that the user id and token are displayed directly, only using url encoding on the address bar of the browser.

```
http://hasconpanel.ckoysolutions.com/hasconpanel.php?inputs={%20%22username%22%20:%20%22Debopam%20Parua%22%20,%20%22uid%22%20:%20%2220170520193421DP%22%20,%20%22token%22%20:%20%22Sa2pHyooWPoI79vfvJzLlw7UO%252B2p5hOpBttkEq7LQ%252BjAGm9XEmxfhLAcnJoLbqrsXCp75%252BG1M7nEUoCgsDVbIQ%253D%253D%22%20,%20%22list_of_devices%22%20:%20[{%22device_code%22:%22b8:27:eb:f1:b3:0f%22,%22device_name%22:%22First-Pi%22}]%20}
```

Now, if this address is copied, or suppose the browser is made to resume the previous session, no matter who tries to access it, they get an entry. Especially in case of public computer centers, if anyone accesses my web app with their credentials, and forgets to logout before killing the browser, the token system seems to fail miserably. Is there anyway to secure the token like encrypting it? Or someway for the app to not store the parameters in case of a browser/browser-tab close or at least not display it on the address bar? I have thought of making a fresh token at each request, but it slows the system drastically, so I want to avoid it.

Please suggest some way to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Explaining how the system works now:

The api system is hosted on the main domain of a shared server, and the app is hosted in a sub-domain. The main domain also hosts several webservices that are being called from a few raspberry pis installed at home.

This is how it works, the login is made from the primary website and on successful login, the web app is called with a get call with the user id, the token and a list of working devices for the user. Check is provided to prevent the app page being accessed without any of these three parameters. On fresh load, the user gets the choice to select a device from a drop-down menu. Now, each of these working devices can have three separate systems running. So, on selecting the device, a get call is again being made to the app, with the selected device added as a parameter along with the three previous parameters. This shows the token and the uid on the address-bar.

Comment: You may use post request for API call.

Comment: Post won't protect him as long as he is operating over HTTP

Comment: BTW, it is now possible to get free SSL certificates, so there really is no reason not to use https.  If people have to register with an email and password then you need HTTPS:  https://letsencrypt.org/

Answer (score 2):

Token based authentication is very standard in the web world.  The details vary, but what you are trying to do certainly isn't crazy.  However, your security concerns are valid, and there are a number of potential solutions:

1. Use HTTPS exclusively.  This will protect your token from being easily readable by everyone in between the user and you.  Actually, do this regardless of anything else.  HTTPS should be considered the default for security purposes these days: just pretend that HTTP is deprecated.
2. Move the token into the header of the request instead of the URL.  As long as you are using HTTPS this doesn't actually change anything from a security standpoint, but it is fairly standard for the industry.  It will also keep the token out of the browser history.

It is strange that you have a URL showing up in the browser address bar.  I would expect a client-side application to make requests exclusively via ajax, which means there should't ever be anything in the address bar.  You might need to clarify more on how exactly this application is working.  I suspect you need to refactor so that none of your application URLs ever end up in the address bar, and instead operate via AJAX requests exclusively.

Still, HTTPS is the most important part.  Your entire transaction after DNS lookup will be transmitted securely, so the token cannot be stolen by a man-in-the-middle.  This is the most important step you have to take to secure it.  If you don't use HTTPS, you might as well broadcast it to the world.  Of course, if you are making non-ajax requests to a URL with the token in the query parameters then the token will be visible in the browser's address bar and history.  Again, avoid that by using ajax requests only and put the cookie in the header.

Once you have HTTPS in place with ajax-only requests, the chances of having a token stolen are much smaller.  Still, it can happen (in particular via an XSS attack), so become familiar with the principle of "defense in depth".  Also, there are steps you can take to try to detect a stolen token an invalidate it.  Things like:

1. Invalidate a token (for the user to log back in) if the IP Address changes (although this can impact mobile users, which probably isn't desirable)
2. Invalidate a token if the user agent changes (although that can be spoofed)
3. Enforce a server-side maximum session length
4. Make sure and require the user to re-authenticate if they want to change email/password.

Those are just a few suggestions off the top of my head.  Again though, this is a pretty standard problem, so google will be your friend.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for you response and sorry for the late reply.
I will try my best to explain the working of the system. I am editing my post to add the information.